# Inner class as "sensible" default for an interface?

Tags: java, coding-style, interface, inner-classes

I'm extending part of an existing internal framework. Some part of the framework uses an interface definition that contains an inner class. The interface is used as a parameter value for an annotation and the inner class is provided as a default value. The interface looks like this:

```
public interface Adapter<X,Y> {

    static final class IDENTITY implements Adapter<Object, Object> {
        @Override
        public Object transform(Object x) {
            return x;
        }
        @Override
        public Object inverse(Object y) {
            return y;
        }       
    }

    public Y transform(X x);
    public X inverse(y y);
}
```

And this is the usage:

```
public @interface Adapt {
    Class<? extends Adapter<?, ?>> with() default Adapter.IDENTITY.class;
}
```

Although the usage looks neat, this construct seems to go against the 'contract' concept of a Java interface and might be counter-intuitive for the next dev that has to deal with the code.

What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the best practice. There are also instances where a static final inner class contains some static methods that do f.e. locate a specific instance.

Edit: Keep in mind that the interface and the inner class are two completely separate types, the latter just has a common prefix with the former.

Comment: Well, what makes me doubt, is that (at least in this case) the default is for the annotation and not for the interface.

Comment: In annotations, a default value for a class-valued property cannot be null and an actual class must be specified. I assume that there exist at least some cases where a specific `Adapter` class is not required, and a default adapter will suffice; this has been implemented here, and the implementation may even consider the specific `IDENTITY` class to be a marker value and do special processing when it is encountered.

Comment: Also, if there are more properties to the annotation, it might be the case that the with() property is optional, which then requires a default value.

Comment: any refence/doc to this pattern?

Comment: It's not a pattern per se, just the easiest way to do implement it -  one could always have an extra annotation having just the class. Fo examples where it's used see `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum` and `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType`.